# What exactly is violated if your response variable exhibits autocorrelation in ordinary least squares regression?

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, autocorrelation, assumptions

I'm trying to understand the issues with using OLS regression when our data exhibits autocorrelation.  Let's say you simulate a process where:

```
t = [1, 2, 3, ..., 100]

e = 100 random normal variables from N(0, 5)

y = 2 * t + e
```

Because of this set up, there is obvious autocorrelation of y.  You nevertheless build a basic OLS model where y is the response and t is the predictor.

What are the issues autocorrelation like this causes?  In many of the regression books, we talk about issues if variance is non-constant or distribution of Y | t is non-normal.  If I recall correctly, such model violations affect the standard errors of our estimates and thus make it tougher to estimate true parameters.

But I don't recall any discussion on what happens when autocorrelation is present.  Yet anywhere I look, it just says autocorrelatoin or non independence is bad. What exactly is the issue that prevents us from using OLS to model the process described above - and thus necessitates a time series technique.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I don’t think you’re simulating any autocorrelation.

Comment: What we care about in regression is autocorrelation *of the errors*, not an "autocorrelation" such as you demonstrate above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean independent sampling when saying *e = 100 random normal variables from N(0, 5)*, then there is no autocorrelation in your example. Assumptions such as independence in regression models apply to the **error term**, in your case `e`.

What you do have in the example is a (strong) trend, so what you should be preoccupied with is if this nonstationarity have consequences for the ols estimation. [Here are some related questions with answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+answers%3A1+regress*+nonstat*+time+seri*+-cointegration).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there **was** autocorrelation you are dealing with the assumption that the error terms are not correlated with each other [they are independent of each other]. The impact of autocorrelation is to distort the statistical tests (by distorting the standard errors).